# Need A Div To Appear When Clicking On A Link

Tags: javascript, html, css

Okay so I got a embed player I need inside a div, but the div (including the embed link) needs to appear and disapear, using css or Javascript

Heres the Embed Code

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" height="378" width="620" id="live_embed_player_flash" data="http://www.twitch.tv/widgets/live_embed_player.swf?channel=deadpoolyplays" bgcolor="#000000"><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" /><param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" /><param name="allowNetworking" value="all" /><param name="movie" value="http://www.twitch.tv/widgets/live_embed_player.swf" /><param name="flashvars" value="hostname=www.twitch.tv&channel=deadpoolyplays&auto_play=true&start_volume=25" /></object><a href="http://www.twitch.tv/deadpoolyplays" style="padding:2px 0px 4px; display:block; width:345px; font-weight:normal; font-size:10px;text-decoration:underline; text-align:center;">Watch live video from DeadpoolyPlays on www.twitch.tv</a>
```

And then I need the same thing for this.

```
<iframe frameborder="0" scrolling="no" id="chat_embed" src="http://twitch.tv/chat/embed?channel=deadpoolyplays&popout_chat=true" height="500" width="350"></iframe>
```

Comment: Have you tried to Goog: ***javascript toggle element on click***

Comment: I just this second wrote this for another question: http://jsfiddle.net/n2jUw/2/. Just click on the "show map" text and check out the code to see why it works.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do this. Using Javascript and CSS, you can change the `display` property of the two different elements to show and hide them.

For example:

```
function showStuff()
{
    document.getElementById("live_embed").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("chat_embed").style.display = "block";
}

function hideStuff()
{
    document.getElementById("live_embed").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("chat_embed").style.display = "none";
}
```

If you are willing to import jQuery, you can simply call the `.fadeIn()` and `.fadeOut()` methods to accomplish the same thing with a nice fading transition.

Answer (score -2):

In JQuery you can use the `show`/`hide` function:

```
$(selector).hide(speed, callback);

$(selector).show(speed, callback);
```

For example:

```
$("button").click(function () {
  $("object/iframe").hide(1000);
});
```

You can find more examples [in jQuery's documentation](http://api.jquery.com/show/).

Comment: Please avoid to give jQuery-only answers to **JS** questions, at least provide first a pure JS answer. + **NEVER** suggest links to w3schools (they are not part of the W3C and they will never be.). F.e: Just take a look what they have posted still today for the `setInterval` function and what examples they provide tor the `confirm` method... (and this is just out of the dark from my mind of the nonsenses they have out there). Mozilla MDN provides cared resources.

Comment: Sorry, Liane. The question doesn't specify jQuery. You could update your question using the native `document.querySelector` method to make it more applicable, but the hide/show methods obviously won't be available.

Comment: With regard to w3schools, it's because they're a really bad resource. You will do much better looking at the excellent [MDN resource](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript).